# Bootstrap modal on another modal

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I just want to show modal on another modal. (Close current one and needs to open new one) So I used

```
<a href="#contact" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#forget-password" data-dismiss="modal">Register here</a>
```

**data-dismiss="modal"** I try with this attribute end of link and it's woking fine. The problem is that the second modal height is bit higher. I can't scroll down to see it's upper content. and input fields looking weird. Please see this image.

[image]

Is there any other way to show modal when another modal by closing first modal?

Comment: Javascript/Jquery solutions will do?

Comment: put your code in jsfiddle. also as @Rithwik said it will work with Javascript/Jquery. And I am sure u use Jquery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
$('#myModal-1').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
        $('#myModal-2').modal('show');
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/princesodhi/ru2rz404/